# Restaurar aplicação minimizada (Login)

Tags: delphi

Tenho uma aplicação em *Delphi* que a tela de login aparece antes da tela principal, na verdade é criada e aberta durante o *Create* do *MainForm*.

Se o usuário minimizar a aplicação na tela de login e tentar restaurar aplicação, ela não restaura fica minimizada na barra de tarefas do windows.

O certo seria ela volta para a tela de login.

Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na propriedade "BorderIcons" do formulário de login, deixe apenas marcados como "True" os parâmetros "biSystemMenu" e "biMinimize".

Ainda no formulário de login declare a seguinte **Procedure**:

```
...
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure WMSysCommand(var Message: TWMSysCommand); message WM_SYSCOMMAND;
...

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFrmLogin.WMSysCommand(var Message: TWMSysCommand);
begin
  if (message.cmdtype and $FFF0) = SC_MINIMIZE then
  begin
    EnableWindow(Application.handle, true);
    Application.Minimize;
  end else
    inherited;
end;
```

A **Procedure** faz com que toda a aplicação seja minimizada ao minimizar o form, inclusive se tiver sido chamado com "ShowModal".

Obs: Por se tratar de uma tela de Login, verifique bem por questões de segurança se não há outras formas do usuário fechar a tela sem a devida autenticação.